# Where to install Miniconda on Linux system?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'd like to install [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) so I can manage my Django projects with order, but I don't appreciate its suggestion to install on my home folder. I've installed many times in `/opt` but I need to alter permissions.

What's a good location for installing miniconda in Linux systems?

Comment: What's wrong with `/opt`?